# how can i do getRuntime().exec with asterisk?

Tags: java, shell

This doesn't work,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("stat /*");
```

nor this;

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"stat", "/*"})
```

Is there any way around it ?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm on thin ice here (hence no answer) but isn't the "asterisk" (glob?) part a feature of the shell (bash, sh, zsh...) and therefore it won't work. 

Maybe you could show more of the errors (if any) you get?

Comment: @adamse - yes. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These answers didn't work so I created a shell file in which i wrote;

```
stat $1*
```

so whenever I need that asterisk to be added i call this file without it,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/my_shell_file /miki/");
```

it adds the asterisk for me and gives me back the output I need, as it runs:

```
stat /miki/*
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 9):

The asterisk is expanded by the shell (this is called *globbing*). So you actually want to execute the `/bin/sh` executable (most likely - substitute another shell here if required), and invoke `stat /*` from that. e.g. execute:

```
/bin/sh -c "stat /*"
```

from your Java process. `-c` specifies that /bin/sh executes whatever is in the string following the `-c`.

Alternatively you could perform the `/*` expansion yourself by finding all the files in the root directory in Java, and then pass those as args to `stat`.

Comment: Note that you have to pass the command as an array to work correctly: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "stat /*"})`

Answer (score 1):

You could delegate the task to the shell, like Brian Agnew said, or use Java to list all the files and directory in / (through [Apache IO](http://tinyurl.com/ylzw9vm), for example), and replace `/*` by the right list.